# How to wait to finish task in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-jetpack

I have a function like this

```
internal fun handleResponse(items: List<TestItem>? = null) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val isDataReturned = testItems != null
        if (isDataReturned) {
            dataModelList = getfilterDataList(items).toMutableStateList()
        }
        requestCompleteLiveData.postValue(isDataReturned)
    }
}
```

I am receiving data through api call so it may be null or empty. After receiving the data I am passing in the function `handleResponse` to filter data. `getfilterDataList()` method is very heavy filter processing doing because it has huge data i.e. more than 1000 items and subitems coming from the server.

So I am thinking to improve code

- if `isDataReturned` is return `false` then I'll send the livedata.
- If `isDataReturned` is return `true` then I have to wait until all value collect by the `dataModelList`.

  ```
  var dataModelList = mutableStateListOf<DataModel>()
  ```

So what is the best way to achieve this?

I can share you my `getfilterDataList` method but not fully.

```
fun getfilterDataList(unfilteredList: List<TestItem>): MutableList<DataModel> {
        return unfilteredList
            .asSequence()
            .mapNotNull { it.testData }
            .filterNot { isInvalidTestData(it) }
            .mapIndexed { index, testData ->
                // more code in here
              DataModel()
            }.toMutableList()
}
```

Comment: You could always return the Job that launch returns.

Comment: @LouisWasserman can you please give me any example?

Comment: You cannot use `var` with `mutableStateListOf`. Compose can't watch for a `var`'s return value changing, only the contents of the State instance itself.

Comment: So 'val' be good option for this ?

Comment: Yes, I was just pointing out that `var` should be `val` when you're using it for any kind of State, unless you are delegating the property using `by` instead of `=`, but that's not relevant for a state-list. Just commenting--it doesn't have to do with what you're asking about, but it's a big "gotcha" I see in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write suspend function which will be simple as:

```
suspend fun handleResponse(items: List<String>? = null): List<String> {
    if (items.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        return listOf()
    }

    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        items.map { it + " MODIFIED" }
    }
}
```

Now you can call this function from coroutine or from other suspend function to get handle response.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to wait for a task to complete while using kotlin coroutine. Simple have a look for the concept of Async/Await. Commonly available on YouTube.

While using Async/Await, your coroutine will wait to complete then execute further down written code.

This will solve your problem.

```kotlin
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.async
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext

class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

    suspend fun performAsyncOperation(): String {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val deferredResult = async {
                // Simulate an asynchronous operation, e.g., network request
                simulateNetworkRequest()
            }
            deferredResult.await()
        }
    }

    private suspend fun simulateNetworkRequest(): String {
        // Simulate a network request
        kotlinx.coroutines.delay(2000) // Delay for 2 seconds
        return "Data from the network"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give an example

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky added the code in answer

Answer (score 0):

By using runBlocking and await in Kotlin coroutines, you can effectively pause the execution and wait until a specific task or coroutine has finished its execution.

Comment: Can you please give an example ?

Comment: runBlocking is dangerous it could be cause of deadlock